# Why use ImageSource.FromStream instead of FromFile in Xamarin Media plugin?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, camera

I am using James Montemagno's Xamarin Media Plugin (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) and his usage example shows an image being updated in this way from the captured photo:

```
        targetImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        });
```

This seems to work just as well:

```
        targetImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);
```

However I feel that James' example must be showing a better way but I can't figure why -- maybe some subtle thing on one platform or another.  Can anyone tell me why the Xamarin ImageSource should be set one way versus another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for choosing either `FromFile()` or `FromStream()` depends on the use case at hand. Also, the methods used depend on the data type as documented [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource/).

Whereas`FromFile()` requires a `string` to a `path`, `FromStream()` requires a `Func<System.IO.Stream>`.

In the specific case you mention, and [the sample hereof](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/samples/MediaSample/MediaSample/MediaPage.xaml.cs), it is sensible to return a `Stream` since a photo is being taken which is not yet stored.

First, [`TakePhotoAsync()`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin.Abstractions/IMedia.cs#L50) is called which returns a [`MediaFile`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin.Abstractions/MediaFile.cs). This class then returns a `Stream` when calling [`GetStream()`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/src/Media.Plugin.Abstractions/MediaFile.cs#L80). Afterwards, the `Source` of the `Image` is set to the result.

In essence, the approach you decide on depends on the use case and data type at hand.

Comment: I've since experimented quite a bit further.  It also seems that the Xamarin PCL, for some reason, does not provide easy access to files.  Xamarin gives an example app that requires 3 native implementations and maybe 50+ lines of code simply to write a text file. [Xamarin Working with Files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files).  Maybe the stream is better to keep track of than the filename . . .

Comment: That could also very well be. If you need more help, feel free to reach out.

Comment: FWIW: *"Xamarin gives an example app that requires 3 native implementations ..."* Nothing in the native code is involved in file reading. [`SaveAndLoadText.cs`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/WorkingWithFiles/WorkingWithFiles/WorkingWithFiles/SaveAndLoadText.cs) is the relevant file. The actual lines needed are `string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");` - to get a place mobile app can write to, `File.WriteAllText(fileName);`, `File.ReadAllText(fileName);`.